# faster erase-remove idiom when I don't care about order and don't have duplicates?

Tags: c++, algorithm, erase-remove-idiom

I have a vector of objects and want to delete by value.  However the value only occurs once if at all, and I don't care about sorting.

Obviously, if such delete-by-values were extremely common, and/or the data set quite big, a vector wouldn't be the best data structure.  But let's say I've determined that not to be the case.

To be clear, if my code were C, I'd be happy with the following:

```
void delete_by_value( int* const piArray, int& n, int iValue ) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
        if ( piArray[ i ] == iValue ) {
            piArray[ i ] = piArray[ --n ];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the "modern idiom" approach using std::algos and container methods would be:

```
v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), iValue), v.end());
```

But that should be far slower since for a random existent element, it's n/2 moves and n compares.  My version is 1 move and n/2 compares.

Surely there's a better way to do this in "the modern idiom" than erase-remove-idiom?  And if not why not?

Comment: `std::find` finds that value for you, if it exists, then it's pretty much as it would happen in C. And it all comes down to, pretty much, identical to C.

Comment: The two code samples are not equivalent.  One uses an array, which can't be resized, while the `vector` version resizes.

Comment: Many thanks; I deranted a bit; pass n by reference so the caller's view of the array IS in effect resized, and found better wording I think than "enlightened"

Comment: Have you considered using a `std::list` instead of `std::vector`? Because `std::list` is a linked list you can remove any item within the list without having to do any copying. The disadvantage is access to elements is linear time.

Comment: @SwissFrank Where both answers use `erase()` or `resize()` to remove the last element it can be done more simply with a `pop_back()`

Comment: `std::list` would make sense for big lists, but many lists maintained by software are small enough that `std::vector` is far more efficient.  Let's assume my case is one of those.

Comment: I am shocked still not seeing a good implementation for this here, after 2 years :/.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::find` to replace the loop. Take the replacement value from the predecessor of the `end` iterator, and also use that iterator to `erase` that element. As this iterator is to the last element, `erase` is cheap. Bonus: `bool` return for success checking and `template`ing over `int`.

```
template<typename T>
bool delete_by_value(std::vector<T> &v, T const &del) {
    auto final = v.end();
    auto found = std::find(v.begin(), final, del);
    if(found == final) return false;
    *found = *--final;
    v.erase(final);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like I could drop that into production code.  Even caching final!  :-D  Still though, for such a common need, is there no more modern idiom than (basically) spelling out the C version (except your version's actually longer, albeit type-generic)?

Comment: @SwissFrank, the standard library gives you building blocks, and you use them to build what you need. If it were to provide all common algorithms, it would become an inconceivable monster.

Comment: You can use move assignment as you use `T`.

Answer (score 2):

> Surely there's a better way to do this in "the modern idiom" than erase-remove-idiom?

There aren't a ready-made function for every niche use case in the standard library. Unstable remove is one of the functions that is not provided. It has been [proposed (p0041r0)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0041r0.html) a while back though. Likewise, there are also no special versions of algorithms for the special case of vectors that do not contain duplicates.

So, you'll need to implement the algorithm yourself if you wish to use an optimal algorithm. There is `std::find` for linear search. After that, you only need to assign from last element and finally pop it off.

Answer (score 0):

Most implementations of `std::vector::resize` will not reallocate if you make the size of the vector smaller. So, the following will probably have similar performance to the C example.

```cpp
void find_and_delete(std::vector<int>& v, int value) {
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), value);
    if (it != v.end()) {
        *it = v.back();
        v.resize(v.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still, is there no modern idiom to do this extremely common operation?

Comment: normally, if you had a collection of unique values and didn't care about order, you'd use an `std::unordered_set` and not really care about the implementation.

Comment: Sure, but I write software where performance is of interest, so I DO care about the implementation.  There are a LOT of sets of data being tracked by software small enough that linear searches in a vector outperform set, unordered set, etc.

Comment: `<algorithm>` rarely provides super-performant solutions. It's there provide very generic, abstract solutions that work on multiple containers and are good enough for most situations. It's pretty normal to need to break out and write your own loops in bottleneck situations.

Comment: Many, many many many MANY articles and books say <algorith> DOES provide super-performant solutions.  I'm starting to agree with you (as an old C++ programmer being dragged into the 21st century) that it is very case-by-case...

Answer (score 0):

C++ way would be mostly identical with `std::vector`:

```
template <typename T>
void delete_by_value(std::vector<T>& v, const T& value) {
    auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), value);

    if (it != v.end()) {
        *it = std::move(v.back());
        v.pop_back();
    }
}
```